# Geometric distribution with locks and keys

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assuming you have 8 keys - only one of them opens the lock. You try one by one without knowing which is the right key.
If the key does not open the lock - you remove it. You do this until you find the right key that opens the lock. What is the distribution of the number of your **tries** until (and including) the opening of the lock.

- Geometric
- Uniform
- No answer is correct
- Binomial
- HyperGeometric

I think the answer is "No answer is correct" because all these distributions (not including HG) is when you don't change the number of keys each "cycle" - and here you do! (You remove the key if it does not open) so your $p$ changes... and HG - I don't see how it can help here...

But my answer is wrong! It is **not** "No answer is correct"

Why is that? Which is answer is correct? this goes against my intuition. Thanks!

Comment: Think about *uniform*.  The proper key can be any one of the eight, right?  So is it more likely to be the first or the eighth?  The second or the fifth?  And so...

Comment: Each key has equal chance to be the right one

Comment: Hey thanks! But what about the fact we remove some each iteration? why that does not matter? thanks!

Comment: Exactly... and so what does this imply about the distribution?

Comment: So imagine you don't remove it. You just enumerate them and go 1,2,3,...,8. It's the same thing.

Comment: Related [Probability Problem with $n$ keys](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246855/probability-problem-with-n-keys?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you so much all ! :)